# Is the distribution of $f\circ X$ determined by the partial integrals over $\sigma(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3988163/37058).

Let $(\Omega_i, \mathcal{F}_i, \mathbb{P}_i)$ be a probability space for $i \in \{1,2\}$, let $X_i:\Omega_i\rightarrow[-\infty, \infty]$ be a random variable, and let $f_i:[-\infty,\infty]\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $f_i\circ X_i$ is integrable, respectively. If $\int_{\{X_1 \in A\}} f_1\circ X_1\ d\mathbb{P}_1 = \int_{\{X_2 \in A\}} f_2\circ X_2\ d\mathbb{P}_2$ for every Borel set $A$, does it follow that $f_1\circ X_1 \overset{d}{=} f_2\circ X_2$? (Note that I did not write $\int_{\{f_i\circ X_i \in A\}} f_i\circ X_i\ d\mathbb{P}_i$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Here's a simple counterexample (although there are many).  Let $X_1$ be distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$ and let $X_2$ be distributed according to the pdf $\pi(x) = 2x$ on $[0,1]$.  Then let $f_1(x) = 2x$ and $f_2(x) = 1$.  Calculate
\begin{align*}
\int_{X_1 \in A} f_1 \circ X_1 \,d\mathbb{P} &= \int_{X_1 \in A} 2X_1 \,d\mathbb{P} = \int_A 2x \,dx \\
\int_{X_2 \in A} f_2 \circ X_2 \,d\mathbb{P} &= \int_{X_2 \in A} 1\,d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(X_2 \in A) = \int_A 2x \,dx.
\end{align*}
But the distribution of $f_1 \circ X_1$ is normalized Lebesgue measure on $[0,2]$ and the distribution of $f_2 \circ X_2$ is a point mass at $1$.